# Android background service, best way to schedule task every 10 seconds if device is awake

Tags: android, service, scheduled-tasks

**Background**

I am writing an Android Service that

- always running
- repeatedly perform a simple task if device is awake

I am able to make the service start on device boot.
But I am **confused about task scheduling**.

**Creteria:** I want to schedule the task such that it:

- run on roughly every 10 seconds if device is awake/screen is on
- can be cancelled
- consume minimum system resource (CPU & Memory)
- **the device should not and need not be waked to run the task**

I found there are many ways to schedule tasks: Thread, AsyncTask, Runnable with Handler , AlarmManager, Timer, JobScheduler.

I don't know which one to pick.
(AFAIK period of AlarmManager is limited to at least 60s in modern Android version)

**2 Questions:**

- *Which method should I use?*
- *Should I schedule to run the service and the service perform the task once?*
  *Or should I have the service scheduling the task?*

I am totally new to android development. Thank you.

Comment: what is the task that you want to schedule every 10 seconds ? there might be a better way

Comment: @Redman Thanks. I want to query the light sensor to customize the screen brightness.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: read this... https://medium.com/@saquib3705/schedule-task-with-workmanager-an-android-jetpack-library-fb1b7798dfc8

Comment: @MohdSaquib,  Thanks. But WorkManager has a minimum period limit of 15 minutes.

Comment: @pellucide, Thanks. But alarm manager has a minimum period limit of 1 minutes.